# Postgres Query: Ranking posts by users based on user activity

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

In the latest version of PostgreSQL, given the following tables that have been created for a social media argument application,

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  name varchar PRIMARY KEY,
  email varchar NOT NULL,
  password varchar NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Topic (  
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  text varchar NOT NULL,  -- a controversial statement to be argued about
  creator varchar REFERENCES Users (name),
  postdate date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Argument (   
  id integer,
  topic integer REFERENCES Topic (id), -- statement argument is based on
  startdate date NOT NULL,             -- date argument started
  enddate date NOT NULL,               -- date argument ended
  PRIMARY KEY (id, topic)              -- weak entity, depends on statement
);
```

I am trying to write a function or query that for a given user, will rank topics he/she participated in based on how many arguments on that topic the user has posted, that way the site can eventually prioritize which arguments the user will see first. I know it involved aggregation, but I am unsure on how to properly connect the relations. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm bit confused on this. The user is not anyhow connected to the Argument so how do you plan on counting arguments by user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select name, topic.id as topic_id, count(*) as total_arguments
from
    argument a
    inner join
    topic t on t.id = a.topic
    inner join
    users u on u.name = t.creator
where name = _name
group by name, topic.id
order by total_arguments desc
```

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking (changing topic.id to t.id in the select and group by statements), it seems to be working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `author` for `Argument` that references to `Users.name`, you could do:

```
SELECT Users.name, count(Argument.id) as arg_count, Topic.text
FROM Users
  INNER JOIN Argument ON Users.name = Argument.author
  INNER JOIN Topic ON Topic.id = Argument.topic
GROUP BY Users.name, Topic.text
ORDER BY arg_count DESC;
```

and adding an `WHERE Users.name = 'USERNAME'` to get one user's list.

You can check it out on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d98ea/10

Comment: My difference to @clodoaldo-neto's answer is that adding an author to Argument you can filter by the number of arguments instead of number of created topics. Wasn't sure which one you meant.